# ClassCast exception issue

Tags: java

I am getting this exception -

[java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Object cannot be cast to ws.v1.tmf854.snc.http.GetAllExplicitPathsResponse

though i have the code properly casted.
Have a look at the code below.

```
            Object t = expRPC.getAllExplicitPaths(mtosiHeader, mtosiBody);
            //expList = expRPC.getAllExplicitPaths(mtosiHeader, mtosiBody);


            System.out.println("Type---->"+t.getClass()+ t.hashCode() + t.toString());
```

The type of expList  is the return type expected for getAllExplicitPaths().
Since i got classcast exp, i casted it to type Object.

Still i am getting the same error.

Any help is appriciated.

Thanks...

Comment: There are no casts in the code you've posted, so it must be in some code that you *haven't* posted.

Comment: Indeed. I'm guessing the cast is occuring in the RPC code you're using.  I'm also guessing you generated it.

Comment: Yes, may be. In fact i too expect that RPC code is having cast issue. Its generated.

Answer (score 0):

I think the cast error is not in the code you post...

Comment: ws.v1.tmf854.snc.http.GetAllExplicitPathsResponse is the expected return type of getAllExplicitPaths()

Comment: have you checked the version of the Library you use? Maybe could be related to some JAR problem...